# odata action accepting list parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a problem with an odata controller.

I wish to send a list of Address-objects, but the received parameter is always null.

My end-point looks like this:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult SetCoordinatesOnAddressList(IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
    {
        var result = addresses.Select(address => _coordinates.GetAddressCoordinates(address)).ToList();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I have this set up in WebApiConfig

```
builder.EntityType<Address>().Collection
            .Action("SetCoordinatesOnAddressList")
            .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Address>("Addresses");
```

I am using Postman to send requests.

My request is sent as a post-request and looks like this:

```
[{"StreetName":"Some street","StreetNumber":"8","ZipCode":1234,"Town":"Some town"}]
```

I have a different end-point which takes a single Address instead of an IEnumerable, and that works with the same json-request (without []), so the fields in the json are correct.

So to sum up:
My endpoint for an IEnumerable always receives null.
Any ideas what might be causing it?

Thank you.

Edit:

I tried changing my end-point to accept an AddressDTO instead, like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult SetCoordinatesOnAddressList(AddressDTO addresses)
{
    return Ok(2);
}
```

and this is an AddressDTO:

```
public class AddressDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to post this:

```
{"Addresses": [{"StreetName":"Some street","StreetNumber":"8","ZipCode":1234,"Town":"Some town"}]}
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not supported for this resource.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'AddressDTO' from content with media type 'application/json'.",
      "type": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
      "stacktrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\\r\\\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\\\r\\\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just use user definded model like this...foo{inenumerable<Address> addresss}

Comment: and then your api controller action method should be SetCoordinatesOnAddressList(foo addressModel)

Comment: I tried but It didn't work. I edited the original question, with your suggestion. Please take a look.

Comment: try to addd request header... Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get it to work using an Odata controller, and I had to get past it, so what I ended up doing was creating a regular API controller which worked fine.

```
public IHttpActionResult SetCoordinatesOnAddressList(IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

This was able to accept an Address IEnumerable without any setup and it just worked.

Answer (score 4):

What happens if send the collection as a property named addresses on an object, like this?

```
{"addresses": [{"StreetName":"Some street","StreetNumber":"8","ZipCode":1234,"Town":"Some town"}]}
```

Comment: The input parameter is still null, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

For action, why don't you use `ODataActionParameter` as the parameter of the method in the controller?

Here's a simple tutorial about how to use Action:

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support

In which, section "**Entity and Collection of Entity parameter**" is the same scenario, because I see you defined "Address" as entity type.

> builder.EntityType()....

However, "**Complex and Collection of Complex parameter**" is the scenario for complex type.

Answer (score 3):

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("SetCoordinatesOnAddressList")]
public IHttpActionResult SetCoordinatesOnAddressList(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    IEnumerable<Address> addresses =  parameters["addresses"] as IEnumerable<Address>;
    var result = addresses.Select(address => _coordinates.GetAddressCoordinates(address)).ToList();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

WebAPIConfig should look like this

```
builder.Action("SetCoordinatesOnAddressList").Returns<IHttpActionResult>().CollectionParameter<Address>("addresses");
```

it is not bound to entity therefore access like this
     localhost/odata/SetCoordinatesOnAddressList

Comment: this should be an accepted answer - setting `CollectionParameter` did the job.